# Query Error of Not a single group function

Tags: sql, oracle

here is my query it is showing "not a single-group group function" kindly correct my query

```
SELECT gc.CHART_OF_ACCOUNT_CODE,
       gc.DESCRIPTION,
       GVA.DIVISION,
       SUM(SUM(gva.debit) - SUM(gva.credit)) Allocation,
       get_data_value_desc(gva.DIVISION, 105) VALUE_SET_DESCRIPTION
  FROM GL_VOUCHER_ALLOCATION gva, gl_chart_of_accounts gc
 WHERE GVA.ACCOUNT_ID = GC.CHART_OF_ACCOUNT_ID
   AND Gc.ALLOCATION_ID = Gva.ALLOCATION_TYPE 
HAVING SUM(gva.debit) - SUM(gva.credit) > 0
 GROUP BY gc.CHART_OF_ACCOUNT_CODE, gc.DESCRIPTION, GVA.DIVISION
```

Comment: No @stickybit , that's not the case. Have a look at [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=3d44256c2de34336a28eb66fab783bbf)

Comment: Having must be after the Group By, no ? Having a "simily" Where for the Group clause.

Comment: No [that](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=4e6a54b4b2ee3303061a1997d30ca894)( *having* may come prior to *group by* ) is also possible @Nando

Comment: This column `get_data_value_desc(gva.DIVISION, 105) VALUE_SET_DESCRIPTION` is not in `group by`. Try adding that in `group by` as well

Comment: @KhuramShehzad . . . Sample data and desired results would help.

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
select
    gc.CHART_OF_ACCOUNT_CODE,
    gc.DESCRIPTION,
    GVA.DIVISION,
    sum(sum(gva.debit) - sum(gva.credit)) Allocation,
    get_data_value_desc(gva.DIVISION, 105) VALUE_SET_DESCRIPTION
from
    GL_VOUCHER_ALLOCATION gva,
    gl_chart_of_accounts gc
where
    GVA.ACCOUNT_ID = GC.CHART_OF_ACCOUNT_ID
    and Gc.ALLOCATION_ID = Gva.ALLOCATION_TYPE
group by
    gc.CHART_OF_ACCOUNT_CODE,
    gc.DESCRIPTION,
    GVA.DIVISION,
    get_data_value_desc(gva.DIVISION, 105) VALUE_SET_DESCRIPTION
having
    sum(gva.debit) - sum(gva.credit) > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Learn to use  proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.  Then this should work:

```
SELECT gc.CHART_OF_ACCOUNT_CODE, gc.DESCRIPTION,
       GVA.DIVISION,
       (SUM(gva.debit) - SUM(gva.credit)) as Allocation,
       get_data_value_desc(gva.DIVISION, 105) as VALUE_SET_DESCRIPTION
FROM GL_VOUCHER_ALLOCATION gva JOIN
     gl_chart_of_accounts gc
     ON GVA.ACCOUNT_ID = GC.CHART_OF_ACCOUNT_ID AND
        Gc.ALLOCATION_ID = Gva.ALLOCATION_TYPE 
GROUP BY gc.CHART_OF_ACCOUNT_CODE, gc.DESCRIPTION, GVA.DIVISION
HAVING SUM(gva.debit) - SUM(gva.credit) > 0;
```

I don't think you intend nested `SUM()`s, in which case the `HAVING` clause in the wrong place.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan . . . What I really meant to say is that I don't think the OP intends nested sums.

Answer (score 0):

One option might be to slighltly adjust your current query (used as a CTE in my example):

```
WITH temp
     AS (  SELECT gc.chart_of_account_code,
                  gc.description,
                  gva.division,
                  SUM (gva.debit) sum_debit,
                  SUM (gva.credit) sum_credit,
                  get_data_value_desc (gva.division, 105) value_set_description
             FROM gl_voucher_allocation gva, gl_chart_of_accounts gc
            WHERE     gva.account_id = gc.chart_of_account_id
                  AND gc.allocation_id = gva.allocation_type
         GROUP BY gc.chart_of_account_code, gc.description, gva.division)
SELECT chart_of_account_code,
       description,
       division,
       sum_debit - sum_credit allocation,
       value_set_description
  FROM temp
 WHERE sum_debit - sum_credit > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks for answers respected sir
now this code is working fine

```
Select Gc.Chart_of_account_code,
         Gc.Description,
         Gva.Division,
         GVA.COMPANY,
         GVA.BRANCH,
         GA.V_DATE,
         Sum ( (Gva.Debit) - (Gva.Credit)) Allocation,
         Get_data_value_desc (Gva.Division, 105) Value_set_description
    From Gl_voucher_allocation Gva, 
         Gl_chart_of_accounts Gc,
         Gl_allocations ga
   Where Gva.Account_id = Gc.Chart_of_account_id
         And Gc.Allocation_id = Gva.Allocation_type
  Having Sum (Gva.Debit) - Sum (Gva.Credit) > 0
Group By Gc.Chart_of_account_code, 
         Gc.Description, 
         Gva.Division,
         GVA.COMPANY,
         GVA.BRANCH,
         GA.V_DATE
```

Comment: It's better to accept the correct answer, so that other people know what is the best solution.